# Bash scripts - Add value from file and subtract

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have created a script that adds seconds from 1/1 1970 to a file called datefile.txt. IT looks like this:

```
echo $(date +%s) > datefile.txt
```

What i want to do now is to read that value from datefile.txt and subtract the current value (current amount of seconds) from the previous stored in datefile.txt.

I have tried a bunch of things but I lack knowledge of bash syntax and general knowledge.

Most recent attempt:

```
d<datefile.txt
echo $(( d-date +%s ))
```

Obviously this is a retarded solution because it doesn't work.

Im running this on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing :

```
echo $(date +%s) > datefile.txt
```

You can do this :

```
oldtime=$(<datefile.txt)
difference=$(( $(date +%s) - oldtime))
```

I assume you actually want to substract the old value from the new one to get a positive result.

The `$(<datefile.txt)` expands to the whole content of a file.

Also, note that when you want to use the output of a command inside an arithmetic expression, you have to enclose that command with `$()` (command substitution) or else the shell will not know this is a command you want to execute, as opposed to arguments that need to be read directly.

Comment: So i wasn't so far off. Problem is that bash isn't as noob friendly as Netbeans and Visual Studio so it doesn't help med with the syntax.

Thank you both! I cant upvote yet.